# How does one specify host name for $resource?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource

I have resources defined in such way that depending on the config file host name can change. While I am developing locally it is localhost, when we deploy it to qa it is some other host, in production it is again a different one. We control this through config file. Now when I define resources we do something like this

```
 angular.module('app')
     .factory('InsuredDemographics', ['$resource', 'config', function ($resource, config) {

         var memberServicesHostName = config.memberServicesHostName;
         return $resource(memberServicesHostName + '/insureds/:insuredId/raceethnicitylanguage', null,
         {
             'update': { method: 'POST', 'withCredentials': true },
             'save': { method: 'POST', 'withCredentials': true }
         });
     }]);
```

This is fine if one is not overwriting the url but take a look at this

```
 angular.module('app')
    .factory('Dependents', ['$resource', 'config', function ($resource, config) {

        var memberServicesHostName = config.memberServicesHostName;
        return $resource(memberServicesHostName + '/Insureds/:primaryInsuredId/Dependents', null,
        {
            'query': {
                method: 'GET', withCredentials: true,
                url: memberServicesHostName + '/Insureds/:primaryInsuredId/Dependents/',
                isArray: false,
                interceptor:
                       {
                           response: function (response) {

                               response.resource.dependents.forEach(function (dependent) {

                                   if (dependent.type.code == 'CHLD') dependent.type.description = "Child";
                               });

                               return response.resource;
                           }
                       }
            },
            'get': {
                method: 'GET', withCredentials: true,
                url: memberServicesHostName + '/Insureds/:primaryInsuredId/Dependents/:insuredIdOfDependent',
                interceptor:
                   {
                       response: function (response) {

                           if (response.resource.dependent.type.code == 'CHLD') response.resource.dependent.type.description = "Child";

                           return response.resource;
                       }
                   }
            },
            'save': {
                method: 'POST', withCredentials: true,
            },
            'update': {
                method: 'PUT', withCredentials: true,
                url: memberServicesHostName + '/Insureds/:primaryInsuredId/Dependents/:insuredIdOfDependent'
            }
        });
    }]);
```

I have to prefix each custom url with host name. Can't this be specified at the resource level?

Comment: I see that the URL is the same in for all actions in the last code segment, do you need to duplicate it everywhere?

Comment: Query and post go to "Insureds/:primaryInsuredId/Dependents", put and get got to "Insureds/:primaryInsuredId/Dependents/:insuredIdOfDependent"